Ubuntu 24.04 installation keeps failing
Trying to install Ubuntu 24.04. But the setup keeps failing.Tried running the setup normally. Tried running it in safe graphics mode. Tried it with and without manual partitioning. It just keeps failing. I even re-downloaded the setup file, made a bootable USB stick with it all over. Fully formatted my SSD just to be sure. It still keeps failing and I have no clue of the source of issue. I've attached two screenshots of when the setup encountered the error.
Also pasting the log in case it helps narrow down the problem.



can you try to install your system without encryption?

Ok so weirdly enough. I restarted my system and I noticed that there was an option to select this OS (I have Windows 10 installed on another SSD). I selected the option, which led me to the grub menu. From there, I selected Ubuntu and it booted up the system without a single error. Every thing's running fine so far.
Not sure why the setup got interrupted multiple times, but the OS is booting up. So I guess all's fine for now.

Not connecting to the Wi-Fi during the installation works.

Ubuntu 24.10 ran to the same problem but sooner than ever.

I also have this problem with Ubuntu 24.04 installer, due to using AMD processor Ubuntu 24.04 cannot be installed.

There seems to be an issue with the WiFi (I guess the drivers). But several sources mentioned that disabling WiFi during installation lets you install Ubuntu 24.04
One of those sources is:
https://community.frame.work/t/ubuntu-24-04-install-on-fw16-is-impossible-without-disabling-wifi/51131
Although the error messages experienced (run sudo dmesg -w) are python segfaults.
I had the same issue and can confirm that disabling WiFi worked.

In the question the OP says it is fully installed and runs fine.

OP stated this in a comment. I wanted to answer the question for those who experience an equal issue when installing Ubuntu and encounter this question.

The problem I had installing 24.04LTS from a USB onto a new M.2 on a Dell XPS13 9365 was that the instllation would not complete.  A small screen would appear telling me to reboot.  I tried, but system would not reboot.
Bios settings were UEFI enabled, Secure Boot disabled.  I found the advice below essential to completing my installation:
How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)
I loaded the "Try Ubuntu" installation from the USB, used Fsdisk -l to discover that the M.2 now had a system instllation on partition 2 and an EFI installation on partition 1.  I mounted the system partition (p2) on /mnt on the demo 24.04, then mounted the EFIS parition (p1) on /mnt/boot/efi.  Next I did a chroot /mnt which made me root on the new installation. Based on advice on reference above, I did a grub-install to system partiion 2 which worked and an update-grub which qiuckly found the kernels I'd just installed but then hung-up running os-prober. I let it run for 10 minutes, then gave up.  I thought I could control-c out of this and all would work, but that was wrong.  It appears that if os-prober doesn't complete, the new grub will not be installed.
Solution is to do all the above, but before doing update-grub, go to /etc/grub.d on your mounted system partition and mv 30_os-prober to .30_os-prober.  That's a "." before the 30.
Now update-grub will not run os-prober, the new grub file will be installed and you can now boot the new system.
It may be that os-prober looks at the bios and that mine wasn't clean enough. It still had a reference to Windows in it, but there was now no windows on the system.
